# Data binding not working without inflating

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am using the below code to display the Device Model and brand in the navigation header. The layout in inflated but the text is not shown. I tried the same code in some other activity where I am using the data binding and it works fine.

I am not sure but is it necessary to use DataBindingUtil.inflate but in my case this view will be used as NavigationBarheader. I have verified in my activity that NavigationViewHeaderBinding class is generated so ideally it should work. I may be wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<data>
    <import type="android.os.Build" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_nav_header_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="80dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">


    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@{Build.BRAND}"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="@{Build.MODEL}"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is the main XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".home.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/activity_main" />

<com.andremion.floatingnavigationview.FloatingNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/floating_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:drawMenuBelowFab="false"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_view_header"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: If you are inflating your xml using databinding, then you can access your view only by that databinding object inside your activity.

Comment: @RoshaanFarrukh No i am not inflating using databinding. To verify if the databinding class is getting generated or not I gave it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your binding work, then you have to set your content by Data Binding way, which must be one of below -

For Activities -

```
DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
```

For Fragments, Dialogs/ Lists -

```
ListItemBinding binding = ListItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, viewGroup, false);
// or
ListItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
```

From [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions) :

> This class holds all the bindings from the layout properties (for
>   example, the user variable) to the layout's views and knows how to
>   assign values for the binding expressions.

So you must set content by DataBinding way to let the XML variables work. Otherwise the generated binding classes will be unused.

In your case if child layout is binding layout then to let child layout work, parent must be also a binding layout, and inflated by using binding class.